# dynamic stylesheet not loading

Tags: php, wordpress, stylesheet

I'm working with a wordpress theme that uses a php file as a stylesheet. It's linked in the head as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/user.php" type="text/css">
```

First I encountered a warning that read

> resource interpreted as stylesheet but transferred with mime type text
>   html.

I managed to get rid of the message by following @F. Calderan instructions on the same subject, however the stylesheet is still not working.

The code on top of the user.php file is:

```
<?php
/*
 *  User custom styles
 */

define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
require_once('../../../wp-load.php');
header("Content-type: text/css"); 
?>
```

and the file contains some basic rules

```
.project-view header a {
background-color: <?php echo get_theme_option('background_color'); ?>;
}
```

to be set via the wordpress admin panel.

Thank you very much for any assistance

Comment: What is the resulting HTML source code of that line: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/user.php" type="text/css">`? (in your browser, using "View source")

Comment: Thank you Jocelyn for your concern. The html output was fine. It was the header information, and **Benjamin Bytheway** solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try putting the header information before because when you echo it sends header information automatically as text/html:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/css"); 
/*
 *  User custom styles
 */

define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
require_once('../../../wp-load.php');
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This worked like a charm!
I had thought of this fact and tried it differently.

Answer (score 1):

Add at the top of your user.php stylesheet file the following line:

`<?php header("Content-type: text/css");  ?>`

Comment: Thank you **Grzegorz**. The line was in there, just in the wrong place